# Make Android open a page at a specific time every morning

Tags: automation

I want to login to a site for 50 consecutive days. For this, I will have to visit their homepage for 50 days.

Is there anything that can be used to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Using Macrodroid:

1. Add Day/Time trigger, then select Monday to Sunday and input the time.
2. Select the Open Website / HTTP GET action, then enter the webpage that should be opened.
3. Select Set Variable action. Choose "New variable", give it a name and select Integer.
4. On the Constraints tab, select Macroid Variable, select the variable create during step 4, select "<", and set Value to 51.
5. Give your macro a name, save it. It will look like the image below:

[image: IMG:]

The macro will trigger daily at the exact time you entered opening the desired webpage for 50 consecutive days.

**Disclaimer:** I am not related to Macrodroid developer(s).

Comment: I really haven't used macrodroid that much, but your answer is very comprehensive +1

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Thanks. I wish I knew how to perform the same with other apps to post them also.